# ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (x)

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I have my app made with Reactjs.

I'm gettint this error when I try to run `npm run-script build`:

```
ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (x)  [./react/stores/UserStore.js:52,20]

ERROR in bundle.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (x)  [./react/stores/UserStore.js:52,20]
```

The error is thrown twice. And the line of the file that is poiting is commented!
And now I try without those lines and I'm still getting the same error.
But this is the first time that I have this error, don't know why, and i haven't touched that file in weeks...

Any idea?

Comment: Don't you think providing the UserStore.js file, at least the line 52 could be useful for anyone willing to help? The line number may be different because of uglifying and minification. Does it work without minification?

Comment: Ok, here's the file: http://pastebin.com/qC7AwRnF I even delet all the main content of the file and it still getting the same error at the same line and col

Comment: Hmm, I have an issue with babel I think, webpack isn't recognizing "let"

Comment: @pmirnd You should have edited your original post to include the code, not given us a Pastebin link. FWIW your Pastebin link has expired so no one can see what was on line 52 of your script.

Answer (score 2):

Well, in my case was that I didn't have `babel-preset-es2015` so:

1. `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`
2. Add es2015 to webpack-production.config.js, like this:  `['es2015', 'es2016', 'react']`

The Uglify will work with es6 code (es6 -[babel preset es2015]-> es5 -> webpack with uglify plugin -> done)

Comment: @IanG not sure mate, I suggest you to make a new question with that, seems few people are reading this.