# using es6 with webpack and babel

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I run `npm start` (dev) Babel is ok, so I can use es6 code. But when I try to `npm run-script build` (prod) it not using babel nor es6 isn't recognized. This is my package.json and webpack-production.config.js:

```
{
  "name": "public",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "boot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack",
    "build": "webpack -p --config webpack-production.config.js",
    "dev": "webpack "
  },
  "author": "Adevcom",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2016": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.18.0",
    "browserify": "^13.1.1",
    "envify": "^3.4.1",
    "fbjs": "^0.8.5",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.7",
    "ion-rangeslider": "^2.1.4",
    "keymirror": "^0.1.1",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.7",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.7.3",
    "react-dropzone-component": "^1.2.0",
    "react-gemini-scrollbar": "^2.1.5",
    "react-infinite": "^0.10.0",
    "react-maskedinput": "^3.2.0",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.4",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "reactify",
      "envify"
    ]
  }
}
```

And:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry:['babel-polyfill',path.resolve(__dirname, "./boot.js") ] ,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
              'process.env':{
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('produccion'),
                'TEMPORAL_PARAM': JSON.stringify('AGREGA AQUI TUS PARAMETROS PRODUCCION')
              }
            }),
              new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({minimize: true})
            ],
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: path.join(__dirname, ''),

                exclude: /node_modules/,
                 query: {
                  presets: ['es2016', 'react']
                }
              }



        ]
    }
};
```

Any idea why is this happening? thanks in advice.

Well, and this is webpack.congi.js where es6 works:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry:[path.resolve(__dirname, "./boot.js") ] ,
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }, 
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env':{
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
                'TEMPORAL_PARAM': JSON.stringify('AGREGA AQUI TUS PARAMETROS DESARROLLO'),
                'AAAAA': JSON.stringify('hola mundo desde webpack')
            }
        })
    ],
    watch:true,
    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },
  //  devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: path.join(__dirname, ''),

                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2016', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: What does "it not using babel nor es6 isn't recognized" mean? You haven't told us what the actual problem you see is.

Comment: I made this question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071529/error-in-bundle-js-from-uglifyjs-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-name-x I didn't knew what was happening, now I see that the problem was uglifying the es6 code, according to this: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2972 I don't know why is having problems webpack with es6 when I try to use the prod enviroment. In the dev enviroment there's no problem (because is not uglifyed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Babel config will need to be changed from

```
['es2016', 'react']
```

to

```
['es2015', 'es2016', 'react']
```

and install `babel-preset-es2015` with

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

Uglify does not support ES6, so you need `es2015` to compile ES6 to ES5. `es2016` just compiles the new features added in ES2016.

#### Update:

These days, using `babel-preset-env` is a better choice than using the year-based presets. I'd recommend doing:

```
presets: [
  ['env', {
    targets: {
      uglify: 2,
    }
  }],
]
```

to compile all modern JS functionality, while ensuring that the output will be compatible with Uglify 2.x.

Comment: Thanks you very much, I was wondering sth like that but wasn't very sure how to do it. I'll will check it later, and for sure I'll put this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks loganfsmyth, for the answer.

In my case I should change:

```
['stage-1', 'react']
```

to

```
['es2015', 'stage-1', 'react']
```

(May would be helpful for someone who use stage-1 and don't understand what's going on here :) )